# How can I prevent the puppet agent service from starting on install?

Tags: windows, puppet

I'm installing the puppet 2.7.18 agent unattended via the msi as part of an automated windows install. I need to make sure that the first puppet run that happens is on the first 'clean' boot of the freshly provisioned OS, after OS & puppet configuration has been applied, along with the requisite reboots.

It looks like the [options passable to the .msi](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/installing.html#automated-installation) are thin on the ground - is there a way I can install puppet without it starting the service or doing a puppet run until the service starts naturally at first post-provisioning boot?

Comment: Are you automatically signing the certificates, then?

Comment: Yes we are - the project goal is to go from VM boot to running services unattended.

Comment: So it sounds like the automation is modifying the `puppet.conf` file after the MSI runs?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit of a hacky solution..

Give it an invalid `server` configuration during the MSI install (with `PUPPET_MASTER_SERVER=nonexistant-server.example.com`), which will cause it to fail to request a certificate (and try again on the next run).

Then, when you're ready to let it run for real (maybe as the last step before the last reboot?), drop the real `puppet.conf` in place with the valid `server` configuration, allowing the node to run for real on its next attempt (after the reboot).

Comment: I've been playing around with this and running into the issue that the puppet service won't stop, the command just waits forever for the service to stop. If I let the service run, it picks up the proper configuration and leads back to the original problem. I'll post a solution if/when, though I suspect it will require further hacking.